# slideToggle Callback Function

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

```
// accordion
    $("#left-nav .block h2").click(function(){
      $(this).next("div").slideToggle("fast", function() {
            alert("hey");
            $("#left-nav, #content, #aside").equalHeight();
      })
      .siblings("div:visible").slideUp("fast");
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      $(this).siblings("h2").removeClass("active");
    });
    $("#left-nav .block h3").toggle(function(){
        $(this).next("ul").slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    }, function() {
        $(this).next("ul").slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("active");
    });
```

Alert works, but the columns are not resized. This is the equalHeight function:

```
jQuery.fn.equalHeight=function() {
var maxHeight=0;
this.each(function(){
 if (this.offsetHeight>maxHeight) {maxHeight=this.offsetHeight;}
});
this.each(function(){
 $(this).height(maxHeight + "px");
 if (this.offsetHeight>maxHeight) {
  $(this).height((maxHeight-(this.offsetHeight-maxHeight))+"px");
 }
});
};
```

BTW, can my accordion menu be rewritten better?

Many Thanks!

Comment: have you tried putting an alert inside the callback to see if it reaches it. If it does then the code that we are after is in your equalHeight function.

Comment: alert works, but not the equalheight function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery.fn.equalHeight=function() {
  var maxHeight=0;
  this.each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
      maxHeight = $(this).height();
    }
  });
  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
  });
};
```

NOTE: Make sure this is defined before you call it in your accordion code :).

If all else fails, try this [plugin](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/).

Comment: Doesn't work either. Is it a problem with the equalheight function?

Comment: If you are getting an error of equalHeight is not a function its because your calling it before you have defined it.